# Load Balance Server Across Multiple Ethernet Ports

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, ethernet, windows-server, load-balancer

I have a server that 20+ workstations must remote into in order to do everyday business.

Is there such a thing as load balancing through multiple ethernet ports? How can it be configured?

---

The software we use for everyday work is simply a RDP to the server which launches a program that runs on the server upon connection.

The server is a Dell R720 with 6 ethernet/nic ports.   The Dell R720 is running Windows Server 2008 Standard 32-bit.

Comment: Do you have a reason you want to do this?  Do you have evidence that a single port is not enough?

Comment: Well the machines show poor performance which I thought load balancing with at least an additional port would considerably improve it.  Curiosity kind of got me going too.

Comment: What server OS?

Comment: The Dell R720 is running Windows Server 2008 Standard 32-bit.

Comment: Look into the performance monitor and make sure that the network is really the bottleneck.  I would guess that its probably not.  I would make sure that CPU and memory and not being exhausted too.

Comment: I think the search terms you are looking for are "NIC teaming" or "Link Aggregation". Should be some sort of a driver feature i think, maybe you need a special driver for your NIC. That is the way it works or worked for Broadcom NICs at least. The "finding the bottleneck first" approach is of course superior! ;-)

Comment: You're right @heavyd. I'm ranging between 0.02-0.13% utilization @ 100Mbps. Could it just be the performance of the software that is poor?  Is something like I'm asking possible though?

Comment: Could be the software.  Could be a lot of things really. I would be worried about RAM if you have 15-20 people logging into a machine with only 2GB or RAM.  And, yes it is possible.  I'd look into setting up DNS for the machine and have that handle the load balancing if I were going to do it.

Comment: I would agree with heavyd, especially on a 32bit machine, RAM is very likely to be the issue with 20 sessions on there. According to [these recommendations](http://blogs.technet.com/b/iftekhar/archive/2010/02/10/rds-hardware-sizing-and-capacity-planning-guidance.aspx) your 32bit OS can only roughly adress the bare minimum of RAM for 20 sessions without any software. Meaning even if you plug in 64GB it will do nothing to the lack of RAM. The 32bit-ness of your OS is the main problem i would say.

Comment: I thought a 32-bit machine could only access a set amount of RAM. I've got 8GB worth or RAM in the machine, does that mean only half of that is accessible?

Comment: @gh0st: Yes, it should mean that. Check it on the ControlPanel\System screen (Win+Pause). That will tell you how much the OS is able to use exactly. You said it was 32bit...btw. the last of those recommendations' bullet points is "Terminal servers performance doubles when it is running on a X64 HW and OS."

Comment: That set amount of RAM is theoretically 4GiB btw. but in Windows 7 for example it usually boils down to something like 3.25GiB.

Comment: @TheUser1024, can you reference that bullet point you mentioned please?

Comment: @gh0st: I did in my previous comment. Here is the link again, it is an article by a Microsoft Employee on Technet about Hardware Sizing for Remote Desktop Services: http://blogs.technet.com/b/iftekhar/archive/2010/02/10/rds-hardware-sizing-and-capacity-planning-guidance.aspx